# Invalid argument error in PopenSpawn.send()

Tags: python

Running this on Windows 10 with Python 3.9.6. It's python/pytest. I am kind of new to Python and didn't find a lot of docs or examples on popen_spawn.

I couldn't get pexpect to work on Windows and used popen_spawn instead. It complains that I am sending an Invalid Argument after the expect. I can't figure out what it is expecting or what the error points to.

I am trying to get it to expect a prompt for the password and then enter "secretpassword". I tried to str(), send() ... but no luck.

Output:

```
test_arg.py::test_password_prompt                                                                                                   
do the expect ---------                                                                                                             
FAILED                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                    
============================================================ FAILURES ============================================================= 
______________________________________________________ test_password_prompt _______________________________________________________ 
                                                                                                                                    
    def test_password_prompt():                                                                                                     
        if platform.system().startswith("Windows"):                                                                                 
                                                                                                                                    
            from pexpect import popen_spawn                                                                                         
                                                                                                                                    
            print('do the expect ---------')                                                                                        
            child = pexpect.popen_spawn.PopenSpawn('mkshadow.exe -u u -P')                                                          
            child.expect('[Pp]assword', timeout=10)                                                                                 
>           child.sendline("secretpassword")                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                    
test_arg.py:19:                                                                                                                     
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
c:\python39\lib\site-packages\pexpect\popen_spawn.py:153: in sendline                                                               
    n = self.send(s)                                                                                                                
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
                                                                                                                                    
self = <pexpect.popen_spawn.PopenSpawn object at 0x0000026E49CE8EE0>, s = b'secretpassword'                                         
                                                                                                                                    
    def send(self, s):                                                                                                              
        '''Send data to the subprocess' stdin.                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                    
        Returns the number of bytes written.                                                                                        
        '''                                                                                                                         
        s = self._coerce_send_string(s)                                                                                             
        self._log(s, 'send')                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                    
        b = self._encoder.encode(s, final=False)                                                                                    
        if PY3:                                                                                                                     
>           return self.proc.stdin.write(b)                                                                                         
E           OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                    
c:\python39\lib\site-packages\pexpect\popen_spawn.py:142: OSError
```

Or is there a better way to do this in Windows?

Thanks for the help!